# limitations of cash while traveling

Tags: indian-citizens, money

I want to plan a vacation to Phillipines from India. How much cash am I allowed​ to carry? Also, should I carry the cash in Indian rupee (INR) or I should carry it in USD?

Comment: Each country has a limitation of money that you can have when you are arriving. I know that in Brazil is 10,000 Reais and in US is US$ 10,000. I believe the value must be close of US$ 10,000. I believe you need to search and you will find.

Answer (score 2):

Information got in TripAdvisor [here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g304554-i4228-k8201981-Foreign_Exchange_limit_while_coming_into_India-Mumbai_Bombay_Maharashtra.html)

> A person coming into India from abroad can bring with him/her foreign
>   exchange without any limit provided if foreign currency notes, or
>   travellers cheques exceed US$ 10,000/- or its equivalent and/or the
>   value of foreign currency exceeds US$ 5,000/- or its equivalent, it
>   should be declared to the Customs Authorities at the Airport in the
>   Currency Declaration Form (CDF), on arrival in India.Just one need to
>   make a declaration on custom /immigration form if it exceeds limit.The
>   declaration limit is per person basis .
>
> In addition, one can carry up to Rs 5000 in Indian Rupees while
>   traveling to or from countries other than Nepal and Bhutan. There is
>   no limit for these two countries.
>
> There is no fee or charge for carrying foreign currency into India
>   while coming from abroad and neither a stipulation to convert the
>   foreign currency at airport. You can convert as and when and where you
>   need to .